# Bash parse list for prime numbers.

Tags: bash, parsing

I want to parse a list of hexas that i get from a file after parsing them for unique hexas and sorting them.

The list looks like this:

```
   1 0xb6e38000
   8 0xb6f66000
   5 0xb6f69000
   1 0xb6f6c000
   3 0xb6fd4000
   1 0xb6ff7000
   2 0xb6ff8000
   4 0xb6ffa000
   1 0xb6ffb000
```

Now what i want to do, is refine it even more so that i get only the hexas with prime numbers in front, like this:

```
   1 0xb6e38000
   5 0xb6f69000
   1 0xb6f6c000
   3 0xb6fd4000
   1 0xb6ff7000
   1 0xb6ffb000
```

The command i have been using is this:

```
sort | uniq -c | grep  " 1 0x"
```

But this command lists only the ones that appear only once in the file. 
Can anyone help me "sort" this out ?

Comment: what are the possible prime numbers that can occur in first column? how is `1` a prime number and `2` is not?

Comment: for input and expected output shown, try `grep ' [135] ' ip.txt`

Comment: @Sundeep: Agree that could work, but  a more generic solution for all types of input is what is needed.

Comment: @Inian, agree, hence asking what possible primes can occur in 1st column, and also what is OP's definition of prime :)

Comment: @Sundeep: maybe OP has to re-phrase the `prime` part as you said, maybe he was looking just to filer odd-numbers only, because `1` is not a prime

Comment: @Inian yeah, and OP needs to show input sample with repeated hex values as well, otherwise there is no need to use sort/uniq..

Comment: i sould have mentioned this from the start, i need odd number lines to show up, not prime. My bad.

Comment: " ... i need odd number ... My bad" Please update your question and TITLE ! Good grief.

Answer (score 2):

## Original answer for prime numbers

As mentioned in the comments to the question, `1` is not [prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number), but in the description of desired output you list the lines starting with `1`. However, if you actually want to filter out the lines with prime numbers in the first column, then the following script will help:

```
#!/bin/bash -

[ $# -gt 0 ] && source_file="$1"

: ${source_file:=/tmp/source-file}

function is_prime {
  declare -i n="$1"

  if [ $n -le 1 ]; then
    return 1
  elif [ $n -le 3 ]; then
    return 0
  elif [[ $(( $n % 2 )) == 0 || $(( $n % 3 )) == 0 ]]; then
    return 1
  fi

  i=5
  while [[ $(( $i * $i )) -le $n ]]; do
    if [[  $(( $n % $i )) == 0 || $(( $n % ($i + 2) ))  == 0 ]]; then
      return 1
    fi
    (( i += 6 ))
  done
  return 0
}

while read -a line; do
  # We accept only two or more columns
  [ ${#line[@]} -ge 2 ] || continue;
  if is_prime ${line[0]}; then
    echo $line
  else
    echo >&2 "skipping ${line[*]} as ${line[0]} is not prime"
  fi
done < "$source_file"
```

In this script we define `is_prime` function which returns zero (success status), if the first argument (`$1`) is a prime number. Non-zero means non-prime number. The algorithm is a version of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test#Pseudocode) pseudo-code translated into Bash.

Then we read `$source_file` line by line with the `while` loop where we put the columns into the `line` array: `read -a line`. Then we check if `is_prime ${line[0]}` command exits with a success code (zero) and output the line if it is. Otherwise, we print a message to the standard error (`echo >&2`).

The script accepts optional argument for the source file path. It assigns `$source_file` to `/tmp/source-file`, if the first argument is missing.

*Script usage*

1. Save the above-mentioned code in `script.sh` file.
2. Call `bash script.sh /path/to/source-file >filtered 2>errors`
3. Examine the contents of `filtered` and `errors` files. The first will contain the lines filtered out from the source file.

The output files will look like the following:

*filtered*

```
5 0xb6f69000
3 0xb6fd4000
2 0xb6ff8000
```

*errors*

```
skipping 1 0xb6e38000 as 1 is not prime
skipping 8 0xb6f66000 as 8 is not prime
skipping 1 0xb6f6c000 as 1 is not prime
skipping 1 0xb6ff7000 as 1 is not prime
skipping 4 0xb6ffa000 as 4 is not prime
skipping 1 0xb6ffb000 as 1 is not prime
```

## Update for odd numbers

> i sould have mentioned this from the start, i need odd number lines to
>   show up, not prime. My bad. – biotic

It's easy to detect if a number is odd with an expression like `if [[ $(( $n % 2 )) != 0 ]]`. The expression checks if the remainder by `2` is not equal to zero, i.e. applies the [modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation). If the remainder is zero, then the number is even, otherwise odd, of course.

The full script:

```
#!/bin/bash -

[ $# -gt 0 ] && source_file="$1"

: ${source_file:=/tmp/source-file}


while read -a line; do
  # We accept only two or more columns
  [ ${#line[@]} -ge 2 ] || continue;
  declare -i n=${line[0]}
  if [[ $(( $n % 2 )) != 0 ]]; then
    echo ${line[*]}
  else
    echo >&2 "skipping ${line[*]} as ${line[0]} is even"
  fi
done < "$source_file"
```

As for above, you run `bash script.sh /path/to/source-file >filtered 2>errors`

Sample output:

*filtered*

```
1 0xb6e38000
5 0xb6f69000
1 0xb6f6c000
3 0xb6fd4000
1 0xb6ff7000
1 0xb6ffb000
```

*errors*

```
skipping 8 0xb6f66000 as 8 is even
skipping 2 0xb6ff8000 as 2 is even
skipping 4 0xb6ffa000 as 4 is even
```

Comment: I saw i will give you a example of the full command i was using: 
`cat ${parcer}_brut.txt | grep "map" > ${parcer}_parced.txt `
`sed -e 's/\(.*\)\(0x........\)\(.*\)/\2/' ${parcer}_parced.txt |sort | uniq -c | grep  " 0x"| tr -d '[:blank:]'|cut -c 2- > exclude.lst` 
any idea on how to integrate your solution in this ?

Comment: @biotic, I've no idea why have you added `|cut -c 2-`, but the rest seems to generate the list you mentioned in the original question. Then you might redirect the result to some file, then launch `bash script.sh /path/to/source-file >filtered 2>errors`. Another way is to add another pipe: `| while read -a line; do...; done` (don't use `< "$source_file"`)  from the script in this answer. Simplified example: `your-commands... | while read -a line; do [[ $(( ${line[0]} % 2 )) != 0 ]] && echo ${line[*]}; done`

Comment: the thing is that i have tried something right now and it appears that the list generating command may have some issues.